# How do I search for a substring and highlight the occurrences?

Tags: pdftex, color, highlighting, xstring, search

How do I create a command which, given a string (let's assume just a single word) and a substring (let's assume just a single letter of the alphabet), outputs the given string with all the occurrences (case-insensitive) of the given substring highlighted in red?

This is what I have so far:

```tex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{xstring}

\begin{document}
% this results in ac, as expected:
\StrSubstitute{aab}{ab}{c}

% this prints xyz in red, as expected:
\textcolor{red}{xyz}

% But this does not even compile:
\StrSubstitute{aab}{ab}{\textcolor{red}{xxx}}
\end{document}
```

The last `\StrSubstitute` line is giving me this error:

```
! Use of \@undeclaredcolor doesn't match its definition.
\@ifnextchar ...eserved@d =#1\def \reserved@a {#2}
                                                  \def \reserved@b {#3}\futu...
l.14 \StrSubstitute{aab}{ab}{\textcolor{red}{xxx}}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Bonus points for a solution working with `\scalebox` (which I want to apply on the outside).

This is `pdfTeX 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.21 (TeX Live 2020/Debian)`.

Thank you!

Comment: With an editor it's called syntax colouring: some allow you to formulate your own colouring rules, including backgrounds. // But if you want to see the result in a Latex generated .pdf ... why is that useful for you?

Comment: Your example (including the `\StrSubstitute`) compiles fine with an up to date TeX Live.

Comment: Please, state your *real* problem, not one that you think to be similar.